# Optimizing MySQL database for FAST count

Tags: mysql, optimization

i'm currently trying to optimize my database. The problem is the following:
I have a table which currently stores over 83Mio. timedependent values. They are indexed by a highres (ms) timestamp. What i need to do is count how many times a certain value appears in a given interval of time - for example say i want to know how many times value 1.56787 appeared in the interval form timestamp x to timestamp y. Right now this takes almost forever. 
Im using InnoDB and i already put a lot of time into optimizing the config files, which increased the speed immensly.

Im thankful for any input, as im pretty much running out of ideas how to pull this off. The only workaround i can think of is to create tables which contain pre counted values for fixed intervals, which would not be really satisfying since the whole thing should also be fully updateable (we are talking about new values arriving every few milliseconds). Would another db system be better suited for my problem?

Here is the explain output:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra

timestamp   bigint(20)  NO  PRI NULL     
ask decimal(6,5)    NO      NULL     
bid decimal(6,5)    NO      NULL     
askvolume   decimal(6,5)    NO      NULL     
bidvolume   decimal(6,5)    NO      NULL     

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket= "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 61M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
bind-address="192.168.1.2"


# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Oh the machine is an i7-950 with 6GB of RAM and the system+database is on a SSD. So i think that should not be the problem?

Thanks for your help, it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is throwing money at the problem not an option? You can do a lot to improve performance, and more money is definitely not my first choice... but as some point you just have to get better hardware. According to your description, it seems like you're getting close to that point. That being said... I highly recommended giving (a well-configured) Postgres a shot.

Comment: Without seeing the tables and hardware you use to run your MySQl instance - it's difficult to suggest anything. And I doubt that Postgres would make any difference on an I/O bound system, especially knowing that InnoDB's B-tree implementation is one of the best in the industry. Swapping the whole RDBMS judging by a long shot is not a viable option IMO. I'm betting that the MySQL is not configured properly (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%' and output of `EXPLAIN...` was not present). If you could post those, it'd be easier to analyze what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, i added all the infos to the description...no if it is necessary it shouldnt be a problem to put some cash in, but as i posted, its an i7 with ssd and 6GB ram...

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is only 1 GB on a 6 gig system. Increase it to 5 gigs. The other problem you have is having the timestamp as primary key in an InnoDB engine. If your timestamps aren't sequential (next one larger than previous) then InnoDB physically reorders the records which kills its performance while inserting due to the clustered primary key. Add `EXPLAIN` keyword before your select statement to see how many rows MySQL wants to examine and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a feel for the range of values that you have in you indexed timestamp value but it seems to me that [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) your table could help you out here. Specifically [RANGE partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html) or [HASH partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-hash.html).

This should give you a significant performance boost.

Comment: Hash partitioning is not desirable: it ensures even distribution of data in the partitions (being an hash), but for interval queries (like the one he does) it doesn't provide particular benefits, while range partitionig most definitely will.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, i think i have quite some stuff to dig into now!

Answer (score 0):

If the time ranges can be expressed as a series of ranges (months, days, weeks, etc.), you might introduce something like a date-prefix column, that will significatly reduce the number of examined rows using `IN()` expression.

Here is an article that exposes the idea: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/09/getting-around-optimizer-limitations-with-an-in-list/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I posted the explain output above. I'll definiteley have a look at your link!

Answer (score -1):

First step: if you haven't done it, use explain plan to see what exactly is the bottleneck of your query, and if the engine is using the index(es) correctly.

Second step: partition your table by range on the timestamp. I'm not sure if MySQL/InnoDB has that capability, but if it doesn't you'd better change DBMS.

In any case, MySQL is not really a good choice for high performance: depending on your needs you may be better off with Oracle or Postgre, or even an in-memory storage (especially if you don't care too much for safety as opposed to performance).

Comment: InnoDB stores working dataset in-memory and works much faster than in-memory specific solutions. Postgres or Oracle won't be faster. It's a question of optimizing the system's I/O and seeing why the query takes that long.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that InnoDB would be faster than, say, H2 (and they say it isn't, for what it's worth: http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html). Still, clearly switching RDBMS is a whole other thing to consider and not the simplest solution, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: InnoDB @ 5.6 is fast, and the benchmark you linked states that MySQL in their case does 140 statements / second which is slower than what my small-testing xeon and 7200rpm drive does. I don't trust out-of-the-box benchmarks against other systems. Then again, there are specialized column-based analytical engines for MySQL that are performing faster than Oracle is. The question is why is a db of less than 100 mil. records performing so slow and I know for a fact that you can get extremely quick results with so many rows on InnoDB without changing the db system.