# ...still not getting results trying to optimize mysql innodb table for fast count

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

i posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601237/optimizing-mysql-database-for-fast-count) a while ago. i tried out the suggestions and came to the conclusion that i must be doing something fundamentally wrong.
What i basically want to do is this:

i have a table containing 83Mio. time/price pairs. As index im using a millisecond accurate unix timestamp, the price ranges between 1.18775 and 1.60400 (decimal with precision 5).
i have a client that needs to get out the price densities for a given time interval, meaning i want to take a specified interval of time and count how many times all the different prices appear in this interval. 
How would you guys do this? How would you design/index the table? Right now im building a temporary subtable containing only the data for the given interval and then do the counts on the prices. Is there a better way to do this? My general db settings are already tuned out and pretty performant. Thanks for any hints! I will provide any additional information needed as fast as i can!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a large amount of data and its growing v rapidly I'd be inclined to add a second table of:

```
price (primary key)
time( some block - also part of PK )
count
```

Do an 'insert on duplicate key update count++' sort of thing. Group the time field by some predetermined interval (depends on the sorts of queries you get.. ms/sec/hour/whatever). This way you:

```
 don't have to mess with temp tables - with a table of this size it will write to disk - slow even with SSD
 don't have to touch the initial table every time you want to do your query - might run into locking issues
```

You will have to avg out your data a bit but the granularity can be predetermined to cause as few issues as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im not sure if im getting it right. i want to try to avoid the usage of predetermined intervals for my tables, since the time intervals are assigned dynamically by the procedure3 call..

Comment: I guess that's what im saying - you can avoid a great deal of overhead on your db by making some chunks of the timing. IE Force some sort of minimum interval for this query. The results will be the same when you're looking at a chart.